# How to update json data coming from api in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a React project, I'am counsuming API from backend to know when the person has made changes in Video Call(VC) request. For example, as a user I'am requesting VC to that person, When that person updates VC status like "Accepted", "Rejected" or "Rescheduled", that data is to be reflected in Front-end i.e in React code. I'am using useEffect without array dependency to run every 10 seconds to get status data. But, the main problem here is resource utilization is intensive and backend server freezes. So what could be the best solution to get the 'changed' backend data.

Following is the code for reference

```
const [allRequestsData, setAllRequestsData] = useState([])

const myRequestsData = async () => {
        var newRequest = await fetch(`${config.baseUrl}videocall/list`, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'ApiKey': config.apiKey,
                'artistid': config.artistId,
                'platform': config.platform,
                'V': config.version,
                'Product': 'apm',
                'Authorization': sessionStorage.getItem('tokenNew')
            }
        }).then((data) => data.json())
        setAllRequestsData(newRequest.data.list)
    }


useEffect(() => {
        myRequestsData()
}, []) {/* <-- Here the function is updated only once */}

{/*
useEffect(() => {
        setInterval(() => {
       myRequestsData()
}, 10000)
})
 */} {/* Here the server freezes as it continuously calls data from backend every 10 seconds */}
```

My intention is to update the status of VC only when the person from other end updates status data. See the following code for clarity

```
allRequestsData.map((data) => {
data.status == "Accepted" ? (<h2>Accepted</h2>) : data.status == "Rejected" ? (<h2>Rejected</h2>) : ''
})
```

As seen above the status data need to be updated but, want to display data only when backend data is changed.

So, What would be appropriate solution to display data only when backend side data is changed?

Comment: you have forgotten the `return` in `map` callback.

Comment: Your second `useEffect` should also have an empty dependency array so you only start one interval instead of starting a new interval every time the effect is triggered. The alternative to polling the backend is to use sockets and establish a subscription and push out (publish) updates to subscribers.

Comment: @DrewReese Yes I have also added empty dependency array in second useEffect but, still intensive use of backend data... Other solution you said is socket, but, will that  be effective?

Comment: @Pranav, Your problem is frequent calls to the interface？Using websocket will fix it. The backend only send data to the browser when the status has changed

Comment: Well I have used socket to consume api but, showing error as 'GET 'htpps://..... ' not found

Comment: @YuMiao can you show some example?

Comment: @Pranav https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications

Comment: Your current api is not a websocket api, backend need create a websocket api for your

Comment: OK for that purpose, its giving error as 'NOT found'

Answer (score 0):

You need return jsx using map.

```js
function App() {
  // ...
  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
       myRequestsData()
    }, 10000)
  }, [])
  return (
   <>
    {
     allRequestsData.map((data) => {
       return data.status == "Accepted" ? (<h2>Accepted</h2>) : data.status == "Rejected" ? (<h2>Rejected</h2>) : ''
     })
    }
   </>
  )
}
```

Comment: OK... I didn't add return here but, used in my code...My main question is to update status in myRequestsData and display accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You can check for whether the list has changed from frontend side but that will require a deep clone check mechanism which will again not solve your problem since it will still be too many requests to the backend. What you are looking for is websockets. Using websockets you can communicate between backend and frontend without a REST api. Ideally, you would subscribe to a channel and wait till you receive a message from your backend, on receiving the message you will call the API to reflect the changes on your frontend.

This way you are calling the REST api only when backend changes and they send a message, since thats how general P2P apps work. Since repetitive API calls is not good for performance.

Comment: Yes perfectly said... 'repetitive API calls not good performance'. I suppose websockets is the last solution for it... can you give any example or docs?